# Remove bootstrapped peers from DHT

Tags: go, dht, go-libp2p

I am using golang-libp2p in my project where I am using Kadmelia DHT for peer discovery.
I can access info of bootstrapped peers in the following manner.

```
import (
   "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/peer"
)

for _, peerAddr := range dht.DefaultBootstrapPeers {
    peerInfo, _ := peer.AddrInfoFromP2pAddr(peerAddr)
```

I can see as I keep adding new peers, `peerInfo` list keeps on increasing, even after I restart the program. I am looking for a method to prune/remove existing bootstrapped peers. I have seen a pull request that talks about this issue but it seems like the method has not been included in the library. The link to the issue [here](https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/pull/2445).

Is it possible to prune bootstrapped peers in the golang implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to remove the bootstrap peer from the DHT routing table, or to disconnect it from the host?

If you want to remove a peer from the DHT routing table, you can use the [`RemovePeer(p peer.ID)`](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-kbucket/blob/2e310782ef7bc42d9af3e948fcf21d92b97e56ea/table.go#L307-L311) function.

```
dht.RoutingTable().RemovePeer(peerid)
```

If you want to close the connection to a peer, you can try [`ClosePeer(peer.ID)`](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/blob/43fd678024952f9b71e99376588518f99c198ec2/core/network/network.go#L169) and [`RemovePeer(peer.ID)`](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/blob/43fd678024952f9b71e99376588518f99c198ec2/core/peerstore/peerstore.go#L216)

```
dht.host.Network().ClosePeer(peerid)
dht.host.Peerstore().RemovePeer(peerid)
```